# Re-build Ubuntu after patch

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, patch

I applied a custom patch in /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-041500/include/trace/events. In particular, I modified bpf.h.
Is there a way to re-build the kernel in order to make these changes working?

Comment: "Re-building" kernel means building it - there is no "normal" way for patch kernel's binary files. So you need to have sources of the given kernel.

Comment: I have sources and I modified them. The question is if I can run "make" or something similar.

Comment: Files at  `/usr/src/linux-headers...` are **header** files. They are intended for build *external modules*. Using these files you may build modules, but not a kernel itself. For build the kernel, you need **source** files for that kernel.